# Function Type Syntax

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I know the syntax for a non-pointer function type is like `void (int)`. What is the syntax for a non-pointer member function type? i.e. `class C; void (C::*)(int)`, but not a pointer.

Comment: @user814628 No such thing.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, yea I guess so. There seems to be `void (&refFunc)(int)` for regular functions but for member functions, it seems to error out. Can you speculate on why?

Comment: @user see my answer below. Pointers to member functions are of a different nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is `void (C::*)(int)`.

`void (C::*)(int)` is not a pointer type. Pointers to member functions [are not pointers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=474dbe66d76b950a70be99df25dd28a2-ce759ceac3a1c87b565ff35b2f7d6b5c). They [are very strange animals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx).

They just happen to, confusingly, use a name and notation similar to pointers; that's a nuissance we have to live with.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz no, they are pointers to member functions.

Comment: Whether I have the exact terminology right or not, this isn't an answer. My intent seems pretty clear.

Comment: @DarkFalcon This, like it or not, is *an* answer.

Comment: @DarkFalcon this answer shows that you cannot have what you think you want.

Comment: This is not a troll question. It is an honest question. Can you remove the `*` from a pointer-to-member-function when using as a type in a template parameter?

Comment: @DarkFalcon no, because they are not pointers. (They just, confusingly, use the same name and notation; that's a nuissance we have to live with). Programmers are terrible at naming things.

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense. Perhaops you could edit that into your original answer?

Comment: @DarkFalcon done. I also edited in a link to an article by Raymond Chen that sheds some light on their true nature.

Answer (score 0):

For any class `C` and any non-member type `T`, the *pointer-to-member* type is `T C::*`.

So if you have a function of type `T = R(A1, A2, A3)`, then as a member function, it's pointer-to-member type is

```
T C::* = R (C::*)(A1, A2, A3)
```

For example, in

```
struct C
{
    R foo(A1, A2, A3);
    int x;
}
```

the value `&C::foo` has this type. Also, `&C::x` has type `int C::*`.